# Shell script process is getting killed automatically

Tags: linux, shell, process, linux-kernel, operating-system

I am facing problem with shell script i have ascript which will be running in infinite loop so say its havin PID X.The process is running for 4-5 hours but automatically the process getting killed.This is happening only for some long time running system and i am observing some times after 2 hours also its getting killed.

I am not able to find the reason the why its going down why its getting killed.No one is using the system other than me.And i am running the process as a root user.

Can any one explain or suspect the reason who is killing the process.

Below is the sample script

```
#!/bin/bash 

until ./test.tcl; do 
   echo "Server 'test.tcl' crashed with exit code $?. Respawing.." >&2 
done
```

In **test.tcl** script i am running it for infinite loop and the script is used to trap signal and do some special operation.But we find that **test.tcl** is also going down.
So is there any way from where i capture who and how it gets killed.

Comment: One possibility is excessive memory consumption due to a memory leak.

Comment: Without posting the script it's unlikely you'll get any help.  There could be anything wrong, from a memory leak, something enforcing CPU time limits, to even intermittent memory errors.

Comment: There is no memory issue

Comment: @JimGarrison please check the modified que.

Comment: Are you capturing stdout _and_ stderr to a file? What is the output when the process gets killed?

Comment: @JimGarrison its stdout only.....we are not able to capture because we dont know the idjact time of issue so its coming randomly

Answer (score 3):

Enable core dump in your system, it is the most commonly used method for app crash analysis. I know it is a bit painful to gdb core file, but more or less you can find something out of it. 
Here is a reference link for you.(http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-core-dumps.html).

Another way to do this is tracing you script by "strace -p PID-X", note that it will slow down your system, espeically several hours in your case, but it can be the last resort.

Hope above helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Better to check all the signals generated and caught by OS at that time by specific script might be one of signal is causing to kill your process.